# lose data when write and read parquet files

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I'm starting to use spark, I noticed when I write a spark dataframe with parquet files, and do a read afterwards, I always have lost rows
befor write a file a dataframe hase 20 rows, but when i read i get just 14 rows

```
    sparkDF3=sparkDF3.select("ID")
    sparkDF4 =sparkDF3.withColumn("ID",col("ID").cast(StringType())) 
    print((sparkDF4.count(), len(sparkDF4.columns)))
    sparkDF4.write.mode('append').parquet("SparkOutput")

    dffpq = pd.read_parquet("SparkOutput",engine='pyarrow')

    print("nb row",dffpq.shape[0])
    print("nb columns row",dffpq.shape[1])
```

Any idea please  ?

get the same row number

Comment: Please whan a set master at default value like local[*], i can get all data, but whet i set the master as ip_adresse:7979 i get just a part of data !!!